# Writing the source of the javascript file with handlebars destroys the website

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, src

I am new to Handlebars, this framework that I use called Gorilla uses handlebars to reference resources in templates. My resource is an URL to JS script. `resource` is helper that works well in most contexts, however:

```
<script src={{{ resource 'mytimer.js' }}}>

    </script>
```

This completely collapses the website, furthermore it writes some output.

```
    + alias3((helpers.resource || (depth0 && depth0.resource) || alias2).call(alias1,"mytimer.js",{"name":"resource","hash":{},"data":data}))
    + "</h1>\n  <h4>"
```

I've tried using `{{{` instead of `{{` to get the raw string. I've tried to just write the URL by itself `{{ resource 'mytimer.js' }}` and this works fine. I used it as a link in `<a>` element and it works fine as well. Hence it must have something with the fact that I am writing the address of the script. Any ideas why this is not working.

Comment: Where is `resource` defined?  I'm not seeing it in the [Handlebars docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/).

Comment: It is defined by the framework. As I said just writing the URL works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The output is what Handlebars writes to execute the template.

In the snippet

```
<script src={{{ resource 'mytimer.js' }}}>

    </script>
```

`resource` appears to be a Gorilla Handlebars Helper function that accepts `mytimer.js` as an argument.

`mytimer.js` must point to the resource where the file is located. It is possible this is not the location of the resource, for example it might be `./js/mytimer.js` relative to the location of the document in the server folder system.

I am not certain it is necessary to use triple enclosure to obtain a template literal output. I would think you can just use the double enclosure.

Comment: No, resource is a helper that brings the correct address. As I previously stated in the question, the address is not the problem, the problem only occurs when using it as the source of the JS file.